# How do I make a winforms progress bar move vertically in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, progress-bar

I'm working on a WinForms Jukebox.
I'd like to have a vertical ProgressBar for the volume control.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please don't use a progress bar for this; a vertical trackbar is the most appropriate control. Progress bars are designed for visual output, and abusing controls in this manner leads to awkward user interfaces.

Comment: That's a good point. I saw "vertical progress bar" and didn't look at the rest. A progress bar probably isn't the thing to use to show the level of a volume control.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know that I'd use a progress bar to **control** the volume, but to **display** the volume level you could use a user drawn control or you could just resize a label with a background color (that last method is kind of kludgy though)

The progress bar isn't meant to take input, no matter what the orientation.

If you really would like to **control** the volume, consider using a vertical scroll bar, or a trackbar with [a vertical orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.orientation.aspx).

For what it's worth, there's [a discussion on how to create a vertical progress bar on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60b2493d-c8ff-495d-b845-d114fe456f54/), where they suggest doing this:

```
using System; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 

public class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar { 
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams { 
    get { 
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; 
      cp.Style |= 0x04; 
      return cp; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

which sets the `PBS_VERTICAL` flag in `Style`.

Comment: Add the following to your class and the size will be set correctly when you drag the control to your form.
        protected override System.Drawing.Size DefaultSize {
            get {
                return new System.Drawing.Size(23,100);
            }
        }

Comment: This is totally working 100%. BUT i needed 3hours to make it works for one idiotic reason. So i prefer to add a little detail here so nobody will have this huge pain ^^ I was using this while my progress bar was already on the designer. SO, after adding this code to yours, be sure the "AutoToolBoxPopulate" option is set to TRUE in "tools>options>Windows Forms Designer>General". Then build your program (debug or anything). Then close it, and go back to designer.  new tool will pop on top of the toolbox call verticalProgressBar. You can now add it and have fun.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, even after adding the VerticalProgressBar component, it looks horizontal.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the ProgressBarRenderer for that. It's documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer.aspx)

The documentation actually shows implementation of a vertical ProgressBar, so it should make it easy for you. :-)

Comment: +1 This solution worked, but the one Daniel left looked better.

Comment: No problem. I just told you what Microsoft said you should do; it's their framework, after all. it's your choice whether to do it or not. :-)