# PowerShell Forms - Vertical Progress Bar

Tags: winforms, user-interface, powershell, progress-bar

This is regarding Windows Forms in PowerShell and the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.

I am looking all over and cannot find anything that allows the progress bar to fill vertically. I've considered alternatives (such as resizing a label with a background color), but I prefer to use something that already has a class if possible. I could have sworn I had seen something out there like this before, even if it wasn't a true progress bar. I am not using it to track progress, but more for CPU usage, RAM usage, and drive space for server statuses. This is for a useful GUI for a quick report of servers from a dropdown list, something where I don't have to open another complete shell session (I have enough shells open as it is between O365 eDiscovery, data analysis, and other needs). Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very good C# answer [How do I make a winforms progress bar move vertically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597411/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-progress-bar-move-vertically-in-c)

It overrides the CreateParams method to set the PBS_VERTICAL flag in Style.
To make it work in PowerShell you will unfortunately have to use a bit of C# code.

This works for me:

```
$type = @'
using System; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 

public class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar { 
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams { 
    get { 
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; 
      cp.Style |= 0x04; 
      return cp; 
    } 
  } 
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Drawing,System.Data,System.Windows.Forms

$userForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$userForm.Text = "$title"
$userForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(230,300)
$userForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$userForm.AutoSize = $False
$userForm.MinimizeBox = $False
$userForm.MaximizeBox = $False
$userForm.SizeGripStyle= "Hide"
$userForm.WindowState = "Normal"
$userForm.FormBorderStyle="Fixed3D"
$progressbar = New-Object 'VerticalProgressBar'
$progressbar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 50); 
$progressbar.Width = 20
$progressbar.Height = 200
$userForm.Controls.Add($progressbar)

$TrackBar = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar'
$TrackBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10); 
$TrackBar.Width = 200
$TrackBar.add_ValueChanged({$progressbar.Value = $this.value*10})
$userForm.Controls.Add($TrackBar)

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,220)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$userForm.Close()})
$userForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)


$userForm.ShowIcon = $False
$userForm.Add_Shown({$userForm.Activate()})
$userForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton
[void] $userForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no problem with C#, so I appreciate this and I'll definitely give this a shot!

Comment: Now THAT, sir, was a cool trick! I really like the trackbar, too! Much appreciated, one free internets for you!